# Why doesn't exist Java EE Development Kit download?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, sdk

I've been reading about differences between Java SE and Java EE. And everything it seems to be ok. But It seems doesn´t exists a **Java EE JDK**, is only a **Java EE SDK**.

[Java EE 8 Platform SDK:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html)

[Java SE Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

What is it that I am not understanding about **Java EE** and **SE**?

I read
[Is there a Java EE JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438127/is-there-a-java-ee-jdk)
but in simple words, ***why doesn't exist Java EE JDK?***

Comment: As far as I understand, [Java EE = Java SE + additional specifications which are implemented in the application server](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html). Taking an example of compilation, you don't need a specific compiler to build a Java EE application: you're using the Java SE compiler because Java EE is built on the top of Java SE. To me, your question is like "there are cars and trucks. Why there is only _garage_ and not _garage for trucks_? Because if you fix a car, you can fix a truck (more or less^^)"

Comment: Clear, I really needed it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've posted a community wiki answer so that you can close your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop my comment, [Will Hartung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13663/will-hartung) made a very good summary [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2024257/4906586):

> Java SE -- Java Standard Edition, it happens to come in two versions: the JDK and JRE. JDK has the compiler and other tools.
>
> Java EE -- Java Enterprise Edition is simply a standard, and a couple of libraries consisting mostly of just interfaces.

To put it simply, I used this analogy:

*[The] question is like "there are cars and trucks. Why there is only garage and not garage for trucks? Because if you fix a car, you can fix a truck (more or less ^^)"*